# I need to skip first element of csv and select all other in one array

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have one csv file which includes count and file path.
Like

```
2, C:\textfile1.txt, C:\textfile2.txt, C:\textfile3.txt, C:\textfile.txt
```

I need to select 2 in one array and path in one array.
In powershell

Comment: can you add more description to your problem?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh Burbure for you're help. I got solution.

#Select loop count
    $readcount = Import-Csv 'C:\testfiles\config - Copy.csv' | select -ExpandProperty readcount
    
    #Select file paths
    $results = Import-Csv 'C:\testfiles\config - Copy.csv' | select -ExpandProperty path